# Do certain versions of C++ allow dynamic arrays in this way?

Tags: c++

On hackerrank I came across a question which contained this piece of code

```
int main(){

    int n, val;
    cin>>n; //The number of objects that is going to be created.
    Person *per[n];
    ...
```

I thought it wasn't possible to have dynamically sized arrays in C++ so I'm pretty confused about this and would appreciate any clarification.

Comment: Yeah there are compilers like GCC that support VLA's. That's not c++ standard though.

Comment: And please stay away from online code judge engines like _hackerrank_. You'll learn nothing that's really relevant for professional c++ programming.

Comment: What would you suggest instead? I just want to prepare myself for coding interviews which don't necessarily reflect what actual programming is like.

Comment: The usual and best practice is to use a `std::vector` instead. Raw c-style arrays aren't really a good way to go anyways.

Comment: _"for coding interviews which don't necessarily reflect what actual programming is like."_ Just surprise them. If you can't, the company is probably doing shit, and you don't want to attend there. I personally won't attend any company which is annoying me with stupid apprentice tests anyway BTW. I'd just leave the interview immediately.